# Strange Behaviour - Accessing External Instance Method

Tags: objective-c, class, methods, cocos2d-iphone, accessibility

Hey again,
Basically, I have two Classes:
HudLayer and ConstructLayer.

I want to access a method inside HudLayer from ConstructLayer, to switch off/on the visibility properties of CCSprites allocated inside the HudLayer.

HudLayer Interface and Implementation:

```
HudLayer : CCLayer
@interface{
CCSprite *leftArrow;
CCSprite *rightArrow;
}
-(void)switcher:(BOOL)isVisible;
@end

@implementation
-(id)init{
//Create the Hud Sprites and add them at an arbitrary location

     leftArrow = [[[CCSprite alloc]init]retain];
     leftArrow = [CCSprite imageWithFile:@"file.png"];
     rightArrow = [[[CCSprite alloc]init]retain];
     rightArrow = [CCSprite imageWithFile:@"file.png"];

     leftArrow.visible = NO;
     rightArrow.visible = NO;

     [self addChild: leftArrow];
     [self addChild: rightArrow];
}

-(void)switcher:(BOOL)isVisible{
 NSLog (@"Accessed the visibility switcher");
    if (isVisible == NO){
         leftArrow.visible = NO;
         rightArrow.visible = NO;
    }

    if (isVisible == YES){
         leftArrow.visible = YES;
          rightArrow.visible = YES;
    }

@end
```

Construct Layer Implementation:

```
#import "HudLayer"  
@implementation ConstructLayer

-(void)someFunction{

  //Attempt to change the visibility of leftArrow and rightArrow

    HudLayer *hud = [[HudLayer alloc]init];
    [hud switcher: NO];
    [hud release];

}
```

This should work shouldnt it? But it doesn't!
I access the [hud switcher:] method but for some reason it wont set the property CCSprite.visibility correctly.
I put an NSLog statement which prints in my console, proving that it is accessing it.
Its really weird, I dont know whats going on with it.
I even defined variables inside this function and printed them with NSLog and it worked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a guess since I have no experience with cocos2d, but anyway...

I think this part is leaking real bad. You alloc'ed (retain count = 1), then retain'ed (retain count = 2), then totally disregarded that object and pointed your var to another.

```
 leftArrow = [[[CCSprite alloc]init]retain];
 leftArrow = [CCSprite imageWithFile:@"file.png"];
 rightArrow = [[[CCSprite alloc]init]retain];
 rightArrow = [CCSprite imageWithFile:@"file.png"];
```

I guess you're not seeing the sprite disappear. Due to what you did above, you may actually be setting the visible properties correctly, but since you created two leftArrow and two rightArrow objects, you might just be seeing the other one (the one that was alloc'ed, init'ed, and retain'ed, which has no pointers to it).

Also, imageWithFile might be returning an autoreleased object, you should look into that.

Edit (for my second comment below):

Replace

```
 leftArrow = [[[CCSprite alloc]init]retain];
 leftArrow = [CCSprite imageWithFile:@"file.png"];
 rightArrow = [[[CCSprite alloc]init]retain];
 rightArrow = [CCSprite imageWithFile:@"file.png"];
```

with

```
 leftArrow = [[CCSprite imageWithFile:@"file.png"] retain];
 rightArrow = [[CCSprite imageWithFile:@"file.png"] retain];
```

Comment: I only added the extra allocations to ensure that the object wasnt being released.  
I experimented and put this: leftArrow = [[CCSprite spriteWithFile...] retain];  
This doesnt work, nor does any other combination, I have no idea why...

Comment: You did not add extra allocations. You created a dangling object, one you have no pointers to. try the code in the edit part of the post.

Comment: Oh well. Guess you'll have to get help from someone who actually knows cocos2d. :D